# AVPlayer seekToTime not working for seek back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation

I have very strange seekToTime behaviour while playing mp3 files, cannot understand how to fix.

This code

```
    [self.avPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, NSEC_PER_SEC) 
                   toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero
                   toleranceAfter:kCMTimePositiveInfinity];
```

works ok if seconds is greater than current time, but do nothing for kCMTimeZero or if seconds is less. Status not changed after seek backward.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.avPlayer.currentItem) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
            if (self.avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay && self.player.play) {
                NSLog(@"Ready");
                NSLog(@"%lli", self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration.value);
                [self.avPlayer play];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Duration is 0, "ready" appeared only for forward seek. avPlayer is AVPlayer.

How to seek backward correctly? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
NSLog(@"Tracks from asset: %@", self.avPlayer.currentItem.asset.tracks);
NSLog(@"Tracks from file: %@", self.avPlayer.currentItem.tracks);
```

Result:

```
Tracks from asset: ()
Tracks from file: (
  "<AVPlayerItemTrack: 0x608000019850, assetTrack = <AVAssetTrack: 0x60000000d2e0, trackID = 1, mediaType = soun>>",
  "<AVPlayerItemTrack: 0x608000019810, assetTrack = <AVAssetTrack: 0x60000000d320, trackID = 2, mediaType = meta>>"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/)

Also, [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) has a lot of bugs, but solve this issue too.

Comment: How do you "use" Bass alongside AVPlayer and the AVFoundation libraries to fix seekToTime backwards?